# nullPointException...but I initialized the variable (or at least I think)

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

When I first ran this code it worked fine but after testing it with a few different test values I began to get nullPointerException and now it doesn't work regardless of what values I give. I looked around online and if I understand the JavaDoc correctly you get a NullPointerException when you try and call methods on a variable that hasn't been initialized. Which would mean that the BestCustomer object isn't initialized but I can't figure out why this is because it is initialized in the for loop before I call the getWho method and if no objects exist in the arrayList (meaning nothing is initialized - or at least I think it does) I don't call the method. Why am I getting a nullPoiterException?

```
package hwk4;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store {
    ArrayList<Customer> database = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Customer person, bestCustomer;
    int totalSales;

    public void addSale(String customerName, double amount) {

        Customer sale = new Customer(customerName, amount);
        database.add(sale);
    }

    public String nameOfBestCustomer() {

        if (database.isEmpty()) {
            return "You have made 0 sales today.";
        } else {
            double largest = database.get(0).getAmt();
            for (int count = 1; count < database.size(); count++) {
                if (database.get(count).getAmt() > largest) {
                    largest = database.get(count).getAmt();
                    bestCustomer = database.get(count);

                }
                // return nameof best customer

            }
            return bestCustomer.getWho();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your stack trace.

Comment: Which line are you getting the null pointer exception on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update `bestCustomer` if it is the first item.

```
double largest = database.get(0).getAmt();
bestCustomer = database.get(0);
```

In your code, if the best customer is the first item, you never update `bestCustomer` variable, and this will cause `NPE` when calling:

```
return bestCustomer.getWho();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `bestCustomer = database.get(0);` in **else condition**.

**If the first customer is the best Customer. That means in for-loop,  bestCustomer will never be assigned.** It is still **null**.

In such situation, when executing the following code

```
return bestCustomer.getWho();
```

NullPointerException is thrown.